# QGIS - Flowmapper uses only first node

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, flow-map

Running on QGIS 2.14.2 for Mac OS X.

I installed Flowmapper and prepared the three files required in txt format (node coordinates, node names, matrix).

Flowmapper imports the files OK through its dialog box, but then takes into account only the first node, and no arrows.

Is there another step required in order to have Flowmapper chart the rest of my data?